# Make VB.net 2010 app on top but never focus

Tags: vb.net, forms, focus

I am making a "Typing Tool" and am new to vb.net. In my last question I asked about how to cancel a pressed key, which was not answered.
But now I hope someone will help me on another question.

I just want a form which gives users suggestions when they are typing on notepad, office or anything.

**So I mainly want to make a form which will stay on top of all other windows but never get focus (Even if I clicked on a control of that form).**

Answer (score 0):

What you want to build is called an OSD. Take a look at this easy to understand sample project on how to do that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12597/OSD-window-with-animation-effect-in-C